# Linq with GroupBy, Order, and FirstOrDefault using Navigation property

Tags: linq, navigation, group-by

I have the following query (select companies last change before certain date)

```
q = from a in q
where a.Date <= date
group a by a.CompanyId into g
select g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

How do I write the same query using Navigation Property?
Something like:

```
q = q.Where(a => a.Date <= date).GroupBy(a => a.CompanyId ).OrderByDescending(g => ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is method equivalent of your query syntax:-

```
var methodQuery = q.Where(x => x.Date <= date).GroupBy(g => g.CompanyId).Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(o => o.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

I am not sure why you are doing a FirstOrDefault on ordered list rather than using it on result?

Anyways, In this [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PQqrCx) you can see the similar output for both syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
q = q.Where(a => a.Date <= d).GroupBy(a => a.CompanyId).OrderByDescending(t => t.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

This should work for you without knowing more about the data structure or what your trying to achieve as the end result. A good tool for helping to write linq is [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/)